# How can I get react-router v4 defined params with express at server-side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-v4

I try to get the `:userId` "albert" from this url 
`http://localhost:5000/search/albert?query=al&page=1`
at server side but failed, what can I do to get the react-router defined params correctly at node.js with express?

routes.js

```
[
  {
    path: '/search/:userId',
    component: Search,
  }, {
    path: '/search',
    component: Search,
  }
  ... 
]
```

server.js

```
server.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
  const pageData = await routes
  .filter(route => matchPath(req.path, route))
  .map((route) => {
    console.log(route)
    return route.component
  })
}
```

Comment: Are you using react-router-config?

Comment: No, we don't use react-router-config. if I use it this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The React-Router Way

React Router V4 does include a way to extract param data server-side using their [matchPath()](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering/data-loading) function, using their standard [parameter implementation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params), `"/path-name/:param"` route matching.

In this case, it allows me to do a lot of server-side stuff based on the parameter before the express app responds with the page data.

**NOTE**: this is probably not the most basic implementation, but it's a pared down version of my complete SSR react implementation that makes use of `matchPath()`.

### Requirements

- Server-side rendered react app
- React-router-dom v4
- Centralized routes file [(because SSR)](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering)
- Express app server (I'm hosting my express app on [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/))

**In This Example**, a server-side express app attempts to run an "initialAction" function in each component during a fresh page load. It passes promise resolve and reject to know when the function is completed running, and the request object which may contain useful params we can extract with `matchPath()`. It does this for every matching route, again, using `matchPath()`.

#### Routes.js Example

Where `:id` is the "id" param in the URL.

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: "/news-feed/:id",
        component: NewsFeed,
        exact: true
    },
]

export default routes;
```

#### Component Example

Just showing the `initialAction()` function in the component

```
import { Link, matchPath } from 'react-router-dom';

class NewsFeed extends Component {

    // Server always passes ability to resolve, reject in the initial action
    // for async data requirements. req object always passed from express to
    // the initial action.
    static initialAction(resolve, reject, req) {

        function getRouteData() {
            let matchingRoute = routes.find(route => {
                return matchPath(req.path, route);
            });
            console.log("Matching Route: ", matchingRoute);

            return matchPath(req.path, matchingRoute);
        }

        let routeData = getRouteData();
        console.log("Route Data: ", routeData);
    }

/** REST OF COMPONENT **/
```

**Console.log output** for the url `www.example.com/news-feed/test` would be

```
Route Data:  { path: '/news-feed/:id',
  url: '/news-feed/test',
  isExact: true,
  params: { id: 'test' } }
```

As you can see, we've found our param on the server-side using no regex. `matchPath()` did the work for us. We can use nice, clean urls.

#### Server-side index.js

Where the initial action is called, with the promise resolve, reject, and req objects. *Keep in mind this is a firebase hosting example and may differ for different hosting providers - your method for the initialAction function call may also differ*.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { StaticRouter, matchPath } from "react-router-dom";
import routes from "../shared/components/App/routes.js";
import express from "express";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

// Import Components, Reducers, Styles
import App from "../shared/components/App";
import reducers from "../shared/reducers";

// Prepare our store to be enhanced with middleware
const middleware = [thunk];
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(...middleware)(createStore);

// Create store, compatible with REDUX_DEVTOOLS (chrome extension)
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

// Implement cors middleware to allow cross-origin
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

const app = express();
app.get('**', (req, res) => {

    cors(req, res, () => {
        // Finds the component for the given route, runs the "initial action" on the component
        // The initialAction is a function on all server-side renderable components that must retrieve data before sending the http response
        // Initial action always requires (resolve, reject, req), and returns a promise.
        const promises = routes.reduce((acc, route) => {
            if (matchPath(req.url, route) && route.component && route.component.initialAction) {
                acc.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    // console.log("Calling initial action...");
                    store.dispatch(route.component.initialAction(resolve, reject, req));
                }));
            }
            return acc;
        }, []);

        // Send our response only once all promises (from all components included in the route) have resolved
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(() => {
                const context = {};
                const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
                            <App />
                        </StaticRouter>
                    </Provider>
                );
                const preloadedState = store.getState();
                res.status(200).send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState));

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Promise error at server", error);
            });
    });
});

module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Hello Mathew, I am using the same kind of approach as your example.can you help me on when I hit the URL  localhost:3000/news-feed/test it doesn't load the NewsFeed Component. All other routes work except those which have parameters. Can you help please.

Answer (score 0):

Just used a sample node.js app to make a server.js which could be like

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/search/:userid', (req, res) => res.json({ key: `Hello World for search with id=${req.params.userid}` }))

app.get('/search', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!i for search'))

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

For the page number and other url params you can do like

```
req.query['page']
```

to retrieve the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I knew we can resolve by this way.
Just wonder does react-router provide api to implement this task.